Better way to avoid Grub2 password protect on every boot? --unrestricted gets overwritten
I've read this post about only requiring the GRUB password when you're trying to edit GRUB settings, still allowing to boot into the OS without a password. The only solution I've found is to edit /etc/grub.d/10_linux. Problem is, as described in section 6.1 of this wiki, /etc/grub.d/10_linux will be overwritten when grub updates, which will break this. However, they don't offer an alternative. So.... what do we do instead? What's the better method to avoid this breaking on a grub update?

You could just install grub to a flash drive & add a boot stanza for your install, mostly copy from install's grub. Then it becomes another way to boot your system, so you can edit entries. I prefer to have a larger flash drive with a full install that I can use for repairs if needed and a full install can use os-prober to create boot stanza if you do not know details.

Found it! Beckab on the talk page for that wiki has a solution!
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Talk:GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#c-Beckab-2019-08-12T14:54:00.000Z-Password_protection_of_non_local_system_boot_options
Just make sure to give /etc/grub.d/09_boot_into_OS_unrestricted execute permissions for all users, and then run sudo update-grub
